# Max sizing for wheels and tires?

Tags: tire, wheels, commuter, cargo

I was given an old 2006 Trek 1000 and I've been working on replacing everything.

I just ordered a new Shimano Tiagra 4600 groupset last night and now I need to get wheels and tires.

The bike currently has 700x25c wheels on it, with a 23mm tire in the front and 25mm tire in the back.  Both are completely flat and I haven't even ridden on the bike.

Here's pictures of the brake/frame clearance with all of the old components on.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSPk0.jpg

I'll be commuting with around 25-30 pounds every day, ~70 mi/week on mostly flat terrain.  I'm 5'9" and 150 lbs.

My priorities are:

1. Reliability
2. Speed
3. Quick repair time
4. Comfort

With that being said, what size tires should I put on new 700x25c wheels?

Thanks!

Comment: Measure the width of your rims *on the inside*, from the inside of one flange to the inside of the other.  This is the "official" width of the rim.  Very roughly speaking you want a tire about twice as wide as this width.  (For some reason, bike rims often are marketed without clearly specifying the inner rim width, even though this is a critical dimension.)

Comment: Why do you need new wheels?  It is not worth swapping out all the running gear for new on 2006 Trek 1000 even if it was free.  Lube it an air it before you decide to replace stuff.  The used value of that bike even in like new shape is $240.

Answer (score 1):

How much clearance do you have on the front wheel? Doesn’t look like you can fit much more than 25mm width there. With your weight and luggage I’d go as wide as possible. Maybe 25mm in the front and 28mm in the back (if the brake has enough clearance).

Of course it also depends on the quality of the roads.